# JSON parse error: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Array

Tags: java, json

(through reference chain: InternshipService.models.auth.Account["roles"]->java.util.ArrayList[1])

This is my data:

```
{
  "password": "quang97",
  "username": "quang97",
  "firstname": "quang97",
  "lastname": "quang97",
  "roles": [ 
    "ADMIN"
  ]
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: For me its working fine. What Parser are you using ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure your question is a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before you post.

Comment: The json you included is fine.  give more read the article in @Paul Benn's comment and give more details.

Answer (score 0):

This JSON is correct. Make sure that error in this block.